# How to get DOM nodes class list using Renderer2

Tags: dom, angular

Since Angular 4.0.0, Renderer2 should be used to access DOM nodes. I can’t find a way to access the class List of a DOM node. I can easily add or remove a class but I can’t get a class List. Am I missing something?

```ts
    import { Component, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
      selector: 'auto-form',
      template: `<form formContainer class="test"></form>
    `
    })
    export class AutoFormComponent {

      constructor(private formContainer:Renderer2) {

      }

    }
```

[Renderer2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Renderer2-class.html) Documentation

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get any information from the DOM using `Renderer`. The renderer is only one-way - from code to DOM.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Renderer2-class.html

Ok, it seems there are 3 exceptions:

- `selectRootElement`
- `parentNode`
- `nextSibling`

Comment: But why is there `get data: {...}`, and how is it implemented? (e.g. `this.renderer get data...`)

Comment: "This field can be used to store arbitrary data on this renderer instance. This is useful for renderers that delegate to other renderers." https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#data this is only related to the renderer instance, not to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks, Günter, I can read. But I wanted to know how `get data` is implemented in this case. The docs are not very explicit and I can't find any usage examples.

Comment: I can also only read the source code. I don't know what would be interesting about that anyway. Renderer is a class, you can pass a value and you can read it back. Nothing exciting ;-)